# Bridge edge loops - select at least two edge loops

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to Blender and could certainly be missing something obvious. I'm currently using 2.80 2019-02-05. In attempting to learn how to use the bridge edge loop function I'm trying the following steps

- create a cylinder mesh and select a cap fill type of nothing
- copy the cylinder and move it up the z axis so that there are 2 identical cylinders separated by a small gap
- select both and switch to edit mode
- select the 2 nearest edge loops from the distinct columns
- use the "bridge edge loops" function

This results in a warning that I need to "Select at least two edge loops". 
Any tips are greatly appreciated.[image: warning message]

[image]

Comment: remove doubles in your mesh that could be the issue

Comment: thanks - I tried that but the warning still occurs

Comment: Did you make the copy in object mode? Maybe you have to Ctrl-J, combine the meshes into one object?

Comment: I did make the copy in object mode. The above steps are a simplification of what I'm trying to accomplish. Based off all the examples I've come across bridging edge loops _should_ work for the example above but I can also see if Ctrl-J (joining?) would do what I need

Comment: First you need to merge the object ctrl + j

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack exchange!

You issue here is that you are working with two separate objects. Blender can't make new geometry that connects to both objects and still have the two be separate.

To understand this a bit better, let's work through what you've asked Blender to do, and what Blender is capable of doing.

In 2.80, a new "multi edit" feature was added that allows you to select two objects in object mode and edit the underlying meshes at the same time. The key here is that the objects are separate. Once you exit out of edit mode (from working on the two at the same time) they have to again be separate, and thus cannot be joined together in any way.

Now what your asking Blender to do when using the Bridge Edge Loops tool is to make some new faces between two edge loops. Blender is perfectly happy doing that in almost all cases. However, when we think about what I mentioned before we'll see where the issue comes from. When you ask Blender to connect the edge loops, it connects each new face to both loops. But at the same time, you're telling Blender that it has to be able to separate these new faces back into 2 separate objects when you leave edit mode. Blender runs stuck here, which is why you get the error (which could definitely be a bit clearer), because there's no way for it to separate these faces back into two objects. Either each face belongs completely to one object, or completely to he other.

To fix all this, you just need to make your two cylinders one object. Blender will still keep them as two cylinders, but will treat them as a single entity. To do this, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join the objects in object mode. Now you have a single object to work with and Blender will happily bridge the two loops.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed (and patient) answer. That makes a lot of sense and I can see why Blender wasn't able to perform the action as I was requesting it. Of course your fix worked perfectly - I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I copied the objects that were giving this error, opened Blender again, pasted them and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. It only worked when I grouped two items together (highlighted them and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)