# Bridge Faces does not work as expected

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and I have difficults with bridge faces.

When I select the faces, and insert them, it works fine. But when I choose the *Bridge faces* option, it doesn't appear.

I get a message *Select more than one Edge*, so I try it by selecting the edges, but it doesn't work either.

Sometimes even only the faces I select are removed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must join both cubes in a single object to use *Bridge Edge Loops*. See here for more details: [Bridge edge loops - select at least two edge loops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130881)

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: I just try it and it works perfectly.