# How to join these edges to make a 90 degre pipe

Tags: mesh

These two edge loops at the end of straight pipes are identical and I am trying to join them to make a 90 degree pipe. I select the two edge loops and then from edge menu I select bridge edge loops but it gives error and says I must select atg least two edge loops. Why? I already selected 2 edge loops. BTW the bridge should make the 90 degree turn as a curve, not just straight. But first I wanted to create edges between these two  edge loops.

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe the 2 pipes are 2 different objects? In that case you need to join them in object mode with Ctrl J

Comment: See this post: [Bridge edge loops - select at least two edge loops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130881/bridge-edge-loops-select-at-least-two-edge-loops).

Comment: Best to use Blender's Spin tool to create something like that. Quick tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/klyAQYBNH6E).

Comment: yes it seems that they were two separate objects thats why. Now i was able to do it. And spin tool is great, I did with that, thanks John.

Comment: Please help me with this :( https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/313691/184148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the two pipes or you wont be able to bridge the edge loops

[image]

Once they are joined, you can bridge the edges and increase the strength and segments to make the joint. However with this method and the pipes being very close to each other, the topology isn't optimal as you can see at the angle the polygons stretch a lot

[image]

But you can easily make a cleaner pipe joint
First, add a cube, subdivide it two times, remove and extrude the bottom

[image]

then make a 45 degrees cut starting from the center point. You might need to [change the angle constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254013/shortcut-for-changing-constraint-angle-of-the-knife-tool) to get the knife to snap to 45 degrees. Then delete the top left part

[image]

Once thats done, duplicate in object mode, rotate by 180 degrees on the Z axis and delete the top part

[image]

then rotate the newly created part so it fits with the first part, join them and merge by distance

[image]

Add support loops and a subd modifier and thats it, you've got a clean 90 degrees pipe joint that you can use in any project

[image]

Comment: Very nice alternative, thanks. The topology looks better for sure... one question... how do you bring the pipes together in the beginning? Since snapping sucks in blender I had to move them manually so that they are close to each other, but they cannot be as good as perfect snap. Or were you able to snap them to touch at 90 degrees (before even joining them I mean) ?

Comment: @upstream the cylinders were 1M long and wide, so the grid snapping worked just fine. I'd advise you to lookup the new snapping tools that were added in 4.0, it made snapping much more efficient

Comment: I have 4.0 and I spent days on snapping but it just behaves as it pleases although  lets say i am trying to snap faces and i select face. For example, I tried to snap bottom face of a cone to top face of cylinder and even though i select center and face it is not doing it... go to my profile and see my previous question please.. not even the experienced users could do it. Can you do it? All I want is to snap bottom face of a cone to top face of cylinder, center to center.