# Making a Cylinder lamp in Blender

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a cylindrical lamp on Blender. However I am unable to figure out how to intersect 2 cylinders on a sharp angle with a curve on top. Adding link to the product below:

[image]
https://claymen.in/products/table-lamp?variant=41303710204098

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe first follow the shape:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Select these edges:

[image]

Bevel:

[image]

Merge by distance, mirror, rework the topology a bit:

[image]

Give it a *Solidify* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use these few vertices:

[image]

Start with an open triangle made from a rotate plane, for the base.

Extrude and rotate to make the extremity part.

Loop cut and adjust scale to make the corner part.

Add some maintaining additional vertices.

Crease the corner.

Use mirror, solidify and subdivision.